# Storyboard View Controller is not showing outlet for tableview

Tags: swift, storyboard

I'm using Xcode 13. Some reason I am not seeing a outlet for my tableview in the view controller outlet inspector

I created a file called tableview.swift

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlet Properties
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var viewModeButton: NSButton?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedAmountLabel: NSTextField?
    
  }
```

[image]

Comment: An outlet is something you _make_. It isn't going to appear by itself.

Comment: @matt I created an outlet. I just edit the question to show some of the content in my tableview.swift

Comment: Would this be because I created a storyboard file in a swiftui project and trying to connect this to a swift file

Comment: Yes, SwiftUI doesn't use storyboards. They are opposites.

Comment: Also SwiftUI doesn't use view controllers. So basically this is pretty nutty-sounding.

Comment: Is there any alternative for me to create a tableview that is supported in macOS 10.15 and newer

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "table view". That's not a SwiftUI thing either. Maybe you should have just made a old-fashioned AppKit project. AppKit hasn't gone away, you know.